Создаю телеграм бота на питоне, но мне выдает ошибку
Я написал следующий код:
import telebot

API_TOKEN = '7795877895:AAGIDmmmpYNJCtZzLK2I-3vhSddl0MRQ8QQ'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
  bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.infinity_polling()

Но мне в консоль пишет ошибку по типу
2024-11-10 09:41:28,435 (__init__.py:7144 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "message_handler: Commands filter should be list of strings (commands), unknown type supplied to the 'commands' filter list. Not able to use the supplied type."

Что мне делать?

Проблема в том, что первым элементом bot.message_handler ожидает commands (список), а вы, по-видимому, пытаетесь задать func, поэтому правильней будет
@bot.message_handler(func = lambda message: True)


Спасибо за помощь! Я затупил))
